# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured after using reverse()

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django. Here is my issue.

I'm trying to use reverse() function to add 'data-url' attribute to my form in my forms.py file in order to use it in my JavaScript then. But I run into the following exceptions:

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'orthodontist.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import
```

The thing is reverse() with the same url name works fine in my view.py file.

Here is my code:

forms.py

```
class OrderByForm(forms.Form):
    order_by = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=ORDER_BY, label='Сортировать по',     
                                 widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                                 'class': 'form-control',   
                                                 'data-url': reverse('ask:question_ajax')
                                                                                     }))
```

project urls

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include
 from index import views
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/', views.UserView.as_view(), name='user'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/popular/', views.UserViewPopular.as_view(), name='user_popular'),
    path('user/<int:pk>/update/', views.UserViewUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    # path('user/<int:pk>/update_post', views.user_update_post, name='update_post'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('search/', views.SearchResults.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('question/', include('ask.urls')),
]

if bool(settings.DEBUG):
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'ask'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AskView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='question'),
    path('ask/', views.AskQuestionView.as_view(), name='ask_question'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_question/', views.delete_question, name='delete_question'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_answer/', views.delete_answer, name='delete_answer'),
    path('<int:pk>/like/', views.like_question, name='like'),
    path('ajax_sorting/', views.QuestionListAjax.as_view(), name='question_ajax')
]
```

**UPDATE**

index.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from ask.models import Question
from .forms import SignupForm, LoginForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, SearchForm
```

Comment: Is your project named `orthodontist`? If so show all the imports you have written in `index.views`. If not please specify the project name and show the setting `ROOT_URLCONF`

Comment: That's right, my project name is orthodontist. I added my index.views imports above in the UPDATE. Thanks

Comment: This will become me asking you to keep editing and specifying imports in files. ;) Let's do this look into the imports you make and find out if somewhere you are importing anything from your project urls. The next places you need to look are `ask.models` and `index.forms`, perhaps it would be helpful if you add the __full__ stacktrace trace of the error to the question.